# SPTs and systems with Topological Order

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, topological-order, chern-simons-theory, topological-phase

I am an undergrad interested in Condensed Matter Theory. Particularly topological phases and systems exhibiting topological order. A potential research advisor doing a lot of work in Symmetry Protected Topological ([SPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_protected_topological_order)) Phases pointed me to a review paper by Senthil (http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.4015) but I have found that despite having taken some of the CMT grad courses at my institution (many-body quantum field theory, cond-mat topics) there are quite a few tools I still lack practice in. Chern-Simons Theory being a prime example. Anyone know some good review papers or perhaps a good path through the literature for someone interested in doing this kind of work?

Comment: David Tong's lectures on QHE may help?

Answer (score 2):

That review paper is good.

You'll want to look into this review by Zee on (Fractional) Quantum Hall fluids and the field theory approach. http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9501022

Wen's book ([http://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Field-Theory-Many-body-Systems/dp/019922725X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/019922725X)) is also a good resource for many related topics though there are some quirks.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the review by Nayak et al. on topological quantum computation (http://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1889) to be helpful in getting acquainted with topological phases, Chern-Simons theory and many related issues. It is really a wonderful review and definitely should be on your reading list.